# Максимальное число из всех элементов массива

Tags: java

Есть массив:

```
int[] age = {2, 6, 16, 54};
```

И необходимо найти максимальное число из этого массива. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Integer[] age = {2, 6, 16, 54};
Arrays.sort(age, Collections.reverseOrder());

System.out.println(age[0]);
```

---

с примитивом

```
int[] age = {2, 6, 16, 54};
List list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(age));

System.out.println(Collections.max(list));
```

---

C использованием *Java 8*

```
int[] age = {2, 6, 16, 54};
OptionalInt max = Arrays.stream(age).max();
System.out.println(max.getAsInt());
```

---

с использованием `org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils;` (Apache Commons)

```
int[] age = {2, 6, 16, 54};
System.out.println(NumberUtils.max(age));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int[] age = {2, 6, 16, 54};
  int max = age[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < age.length; i++) max = Math.max(max, age[i]);
```